Nullable Reference type
I'm working with a code base that is currently using C# version 7.3 I am trying to set a nullable reference type however it throws an error and says this is not supported please upgrade to C# 8.
I was wondering if theirs any sort of backend workaround to this without needing to update the version

for searchability by other users having the same issue, it would be helpful to quote exactly the error message (of course can redact private information like filenames)

Almost certainly CS8370 "Feature 'nullable reference types' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 8.0 or greater."

NRTs are a compiler feature, which requires C# 8 or greater - since that is when the feature first existed. However, the fact that you get this message (rather than just a confused syntax error) suggests that you might already have a more recent compiler, and it is being restricted by the project configuration - try using
<LangVersion>8</LangVersion>

(or above) in the csproj to hint at a later language version. In almost all cases, enabling a more recent compiler will not break existing code - although you might get a few messages suggesting that you try new features for your existing code. You can suppress these messages if you want a minimal impact update, and address those suggestions at a later date.
